# BASH String Comparison Returning True

Tags: bash

I'm trying to compare two timestamp variables to determine whether they are the same. The variable tempDate is used to hold the value of the last valid date, while the variable timeStamp will hold the value of the next timestamp in the loop.

I am using an if statement to detect if the two variables are not equal to each other, but the if statement returns true every time. The variables are assigned like so:

```
timeStamp=${col2:5:2}${col2:8:2}${col2:0:4}
tempDate=${col2:5:2}${col2:8:2}${col2:0:4}

# Here is how the if statement is written...
if [ "$timestamp" != "$tempDate" ]; then
     #Additional Code
     echo "It is a new day!"
fi
```

Where col2 would equal an arbitrary timestamp assigned as:

```
col2=2010-01-01 00:54
```

When I execute my script the if statement returns true consistently, even when the two variables are visibly identical. Is this an issue with how my variables are assigned? or is it a simple syntax mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [ "$timestamp" != "$tempDate" ]; then
```

should be

```
if [ "$timeStamp" != "$tempDate" ]; then
```

Note the capital "S".

Answer (score 1):

To avoid these kind of bugs caused by undefined variables add this in your script:

```
set -u
```

or you can add the option in the shebang line at the start of the script

```
#!/bin/bash -u
```

Comment: I'd upvote this if I could, I'm adding it to all of my scripts